# How to select only first row from SQL SERVER table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

i have a SQL SERVER Query . my task is select only first row from table. My plan is use TOP 1 . but as the query is so complicated i can not figure out where to put TOP 1 . Please check my query first :

```
SELECT 
  WO.WOPK,
  md.PK,
  d.LocationType,
  d.DocumentID,
  d.DocumentName,
  md.ModuleID,
  d.DocumentTypeDesc,
  d.Location,
  md.PrintWithWO,
  md.SendWithEmail,
  md.DisplayLink,
  md.RowVersionDate,
  d.Photo,
  MCModule.TitleforDocumentList,
  d.DocumentText
FROM AssetDocument md WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Document d WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON md.DocumentPK = d.DocumentPK
INNER JOIN MCModule WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON md.ModuleID = MCModule.ModuleID
INNER JOIN WO WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON WO.AssetPK = md.AssetPK
WHERE (WO.WOPK IN (SELECT
  WOPK
FROM WO WITH
(NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Asset WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON Asset.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
LEFT OUTER JOIN AssetHierarchy WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON AssetHierarchy.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
WHERE WO.WOPK = 10109)
)
AND (d.Active = 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  WO.WOPK,
  md.PK,
  d.LocationType,
  d.DocumentID,
  d.DocumentName,
  md.ModuleID,
  d.DocumentTypeDesc,
  d.Location,
  md.PrintWithWO,
  md.SendWithEmail,
  md.DisplayLink,
  md.RowVersionDate,
  d.Photo,
  MCModule.TitleforDocumentList,
  d.DocumentText
FROM LaborDocument md WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Document d WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON md.DocumentPK = d.DocumentPK
INNER
JOIN MCModule WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON md.ModuleID = MCModule.ModuleID
INNER JOIN WO WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON WO.RequesterPK = md.LaborPK
WHERE (WO.WOPK IN (SELECT
  WOPK
FROM WO WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT
OUTER JOIN Asset WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON Asset.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
LEFT OUTER JOIN AssetHierarchy WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON AssetHierarchy.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
WHERE WO.WOPK = 10109)
)
AND (d.Active = 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  WO.WOPK,
  md.PK,
  d.LocationType,
  d.DocumentID,
  d.DocumentName,
  md.ModuleID,
  d.DocumentTypeDesc,
  d.Location,
  md.PrintWithWO,
  md.SendWithEmail,
  md.DisplayLink,
  md.RowVersionDate,
  d.Photo,
  MCModule.TitleforDocumentList,
  d.DocumentText
FROM RepairCenterDocument md WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Document d WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON md.DocumentPK = d.DocumentPK
INNER JOIN MCModule WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON md.ModuleID = MCModule.ModuleID
INNER JOIN WO WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON WO.RepairCenterPK = md.RepairCenterPK
WHERE (WO.WOPK IN (SELECT
  WOPK
FROM WO WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Asset
WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON Asset.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
LEFT OUTER JOIN AssetHierarchy WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON AssetHierarchy.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
WHERE WO.WOPK = 10109)
)
AND (d.Active = 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  WO.WOPK,
  md.PK,
  d.LocationType,
  d.DocumentID,
  d.DocumentName,
  md.ModuleID,
  d.DocumentTypeDesc,
  d.Location,
  md.PrintWithWO,
  md.SendWithEmail,
  md.DisplayLink,
  md.RowVersionDate,
  d.Photo,
  MCModule.TitleforDocumentList,
  d.DocumentText
FROM ProjectDocument md WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Document d WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON md.DocumentPK = d.DocumentPK
INNER JOIN MCModule WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON md.ModuleID = MCModule.ModuleID
INNER JOIN WO WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON WO.ProjectPK = md.ProjectPK
WHERE (WO.WOPK IN (SELECT
  WOPK
FROM WO WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Asset WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON Asset.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
LEFT OUTER JOIN AssetHierarchy WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON AssetHierarchy.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
WHERE WO.WOPK = 10109)
)
AND (d.Active = 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  WO.WOPK,
  md.PK,
  d.LocationType,
  d.DocumentID,
  d.DocumentName,
  md.ModuleID,
  d.DocumentTypeDesc,
  d.Location,
  md.PrintWithWO,
  md.SendWithEmail,
  md.DisplayLink,
  md.RowVersionDate,
  d.Photo,
  MCModule.TitleforDocumentList,
  d.DocumentText
FROM WOdocument md WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Document d WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON md.DocumentPK = d.DocumentPK
INNER JOIN MCModule WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON md.ModuleID = MCModule.ModuleID
INNER JOIN WO WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON WO.WOPK = md.WOPK
WHERE (WO.WOPK IN (SELECT
  WOPK
FROM WO WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Asset WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON Asset.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
LEFT OUTER JOIN AssetHierarchy WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON AssetHierarchy.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
WHERE WO.WOPK = 10109)
)
AND (d.Active = 1)
ORDER BY WO.WOPK, md.ModuleID, d.DocumentID
```

and now please check the output of my query . there are Two rows . but i have to select only first one .
[image]

please provide me any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrap it all in a subquery -- `select top 1 * from (your query here) t`

Comment: [**`TOP (n)`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) always goes immediately after the `SELECT`

Comment: And be careful with that NOLOCK hint. It has a lot of hidden "features" that most people don't know about. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to SQL it's very useful to set up simple re-runnable examples like this:

```
declare @t table (id int)

insert into @t (id)
select 1 union
select 2

select * from @t

select top 1 * from (
    select *
    from @t
) z
```

And as sgeddes said your solution is:

```
    select top 1 * from (
        SELECT 
          WO.WOPK,
          md.PK,
          d.LocationType,
          d.DocumentID,
          d.DocumentName,
          md.ModuleID,
          d.DocumentTypeDesc,
          d.Location,
          md.PrintWithWO,
          md.SendWithEmail,
          md.DisplayLink,
          md.RowVersionDate,
          d.Photo,
          MCModule.TitleforDocumentList,
          d.DocumentText
        FROM AssetDocument md WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Document d WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON md.DocumentPK = d.DocumentPK
        INNER JOIN MCModule WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON md.ModuleID = MCModule.ModuleID
        INNER JOIN WO WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON WO.AssetPK = md.AssetPK
        WHERE (WO.WOPK IN (SELECT
          WOPK
        FROM WO WITH
        (NOLOCK)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Asset WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON Asset.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
        LEFT OUTER JOIN AssetHierarchy WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON AssetHierarchy.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
        WHERE WO.WOPK = 10109)
        )
        AND (d.Active = 1)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
          WO.WOPK,
          md.PK,
          d.LocationType,
          d.DocumentID,
          d.DocumentName,
          md.ModuleID,
          d.DocumentTypeDesc,
          d.Location,
          md.PrintWithWO,
          md.SendWithEmail,
          md.DisplayLink,
          md.RowVersionDate,
          d.Photo,
          MCModule.TitleforDocumentList,
          d.DocumentText
        FROM LaborDocument md WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Document d WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON md.DocumentPK = d.DocumentPK
        INNER
        JOIN MCModule WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON md.ModuleID = MCModule.ModuleID
        INNER JOIN WO WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON WO.RequesterPK = md.LaborPK
        WHERE (WO.WOPK IN (SELECT
          WOPK
        FROM WO WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT
        OUTER JOIN Asset WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON Asset.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
        LEFT OUTER JOIN AssetHierarchy WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON AssetHierarchy.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
        WHERE WO.WOPK = 10109)
        )
        AND (d.Active = 1)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
          WO.WOPK,
          md.PK,
          d.LocationType,
          d.DocumentID,
          d.DocumentName,
          md.ModuleID,
          d.DocumentTypeDesc,
          d.Location,
          md.PrintWithWO,
          md.SendWithEmail,
          md.DisplayLink,
          md.RowVersionDate,
          d.Photo,
          MCModule.TitleforDocumentList,
          d.DocumentText
        FROM RepairCenterDocument md WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Document d WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON md.DocumentPK = d.DocumentPK
        INNER JOIN MCModule WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON md.ModuleID = MCModule.ModuleID
        INNER JOIN WO WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON WO.RepairCenterPK = md.RepairCenterPK
        WHERE (WO.WOPK IN (SELECT
          WOPK
        FROM WO WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Asset
        WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON Asset.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
        LEFT OUTER JOIN AssetHierarchy WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON AssetHierarchy.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
        WHERE WO.WOPK = 10109)
        )
        AND (d.Active = 1)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
          WO.WOPK,
          md.PK,
          d.LocationType,
          d.DocumentID,
          d.DocumentName,
          md.ModuleID,
          d.DocumentTypeDesc,
          d.Location,
          md.PrintWithWO,
          md.SendWithEmail,
          md.DisplayLink,
          md.RowVersionDate,
          d.Photo,
          MCModule.TitleforDocumentList,
          d.DocumentText
        FROM ProjectDocument md WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Document d WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON md.DocumentPK = d.DocumentPK
        INNER JOIN MCModule WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON md.ModuleID = MCModule.ModuleID
        INNER JOIN WO WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON WO.ProjectPK = md.ProjectPK
        WHERE (WO.WOPK IN (SELECT
          WOPK
        FROM WO WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Asset WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON Asset.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
        LEFT OUTER JOIN AssetHierarchy WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON AssetHierarchy.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
        WHERE WO.WOPK = 10109)
        )
        AND (d.Active = 1)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
          WO.WOPK,
          md.PK,
          d.LocationType,
          d.DocumentID,
          d.DocumentName,
          md.ModuleID,
          d.DocumentTypeDesc,
          d.Location,
          md.PrintWithWO,
          md.SendWithEmail,
          md.DisplayLink,
          md.RowVersionDate,
          d.Photo,
          MCModule.TitleforDocumentList,
          d.DocumentText
        FROM WOdocument md WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Document d WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON md.DocumentPK = d.DocumentPK
        INNER JOIN MCModule WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON md.ModuleID = MCModule.ModuleID
        INNER JOIN WO WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON WO.WOPK = md.WOPK
        WHERE (WO.WOPK IN (SELECT
          WOPK
        FROM WO WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Asset WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON Asset.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
        LEFT OUTER JOIN AssetHierarchy WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON AssetHierarchy.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
        WHERE WO.WOPK = 10109)
        )
        AND (d.Active = 1)

   ) z ORDER BY WOPK, ModuleID, DocumentID
```

Comment: i have checked both script from above . but it is showing error . error message is :Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 176
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: supriyo, You can not do ORDER BY in sub queries as they are applied at presentation time so therefore only applicable to the top level query

Comment: now it is working . and thank you for sharing valuable knowledge . these knowledge will help me in future . thank you everyone .

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (
     SELECT 
       WO.WOPK,
       md.PK,
       d.LocationType,
       d.DocumentID,
       d.DocumentName,
       md.ModuleID,
       d.DocumentTypeDesc,
       d.Location,
       md.PrintWithWO,
       md.SendWithEmail,
       md.DisplayLink,
       md.RowVersionDate,
       d.Photo,
       MCModule.TitleforDocumentList,
       d.DocumentText
     FROM AssetDocument md WITH (NOLOCK)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Document d WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON md.DocumentPK = d.DocumentPK
     INNER JOIN MCModule WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON md.ModuleID = MCModule.ModuleID
     INNER JOIN WO WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON WO.AssetPK = md.AssetPK
     WHERE (WO.WOPK IN (SELECT
       WOPK
     FROM WO WITH
     (NOLOCK)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Asset WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON Asset.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
     LEFT OUTER JOIN AssetHierarchy WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON AssetHierarchy.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
     WHERE WO.WOPK = 10109)
     )
     AND (d.Active = 1)
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
       WO.WOPK,
       md.PK,
       d.LocationType,
       d.DocumentID,
       d.DocumentName,
       md.ModuleID,
       d.DocumentTypeDesc,
       d.Location,
       md.PrintWithWO,
       md.SendWithEmail,
       md.DisplayLink,
       md.RowVersionDate,
       d.Photo,
       MCModule.TitleforDocumentList,
       d.DocumentText
     FROM LaborDocument md WITH (NOLOCK)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Document d WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON md.DocumentPK = d.DocumentPK
     INNER
     JOIN MCModule WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON md.ModuleID = MCModule.ModuleID
     INNER JOIN WO WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON WO.RequesterPK = md.LaborPK
     WHERE (WO.WOPK IN (SELECT
       WOPK
     FROM WO WITH (NOLOCK)
     LEFT
     OUTER JOIN Asset WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON Asset.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
     LEFT OUTER JOIN AssetHierarchy WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON AssetHierarchy.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
     WHERE WO.WOPK = 10109)
)
AND (d.Active = 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  WO.WOPK,
  md.PK,
  d.LocationType,
  d.DocumentID,
  d.DocumentName,
  md.ModuleID,
  d.DocumentTypeDesc,
  d.Location,
  md.PrintWithWO,
  md.SendWithEmail,
  md.DisplayLink,
  md.RowVersionDate,
  d.Photo,
  MCModule.TitleforDocumentList,
  d.DocumentText
FROM RepairCenterDocument md WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Document d WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON md.DocumentPK = d.DocumentPK
INNER JOIN MCModule WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON md.ModuleID = MCModule.ModuleID
INNER JOIN WO WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON WO.RepairCenterPK = md.RepairCenterPK
WHERE (WO.WOPK IN (SELECT
  WOPK
FROM WO WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Asset
WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON Asset.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
LEFT OUTER JOIN AssetHierarchy WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON AssetHierarchy.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
WHERE WO.WOPK = 10109)
)
AND (d.Active = 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  WO.WOPK,
  md.PK,
  d.LocationType,
  d.DocumentID,
  d.DocumentName,
  md.ModuleID,
  d.DocumentTypeDesc,
  d.Location,
  md.PrintWithWO,
  md.SendWithEmail,
  md.DisplayLink,
  md.RowVersionDate,
  d.Photo,
  MCModule.TitleforDocumentList,
  d.DocumentText
FROM ProjectDocument md WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Document d WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON md.DocumentPK = d.DocumentPK
INNER JOIN MCModule WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON md.ModuleID = MCModule.ModuleID
INNER JOIN WO WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON WO.ProjectPK = md.ProjectPK
WHERE (WO.WOPK IN (SELECT
  WOPK
     FROM WO WITH (NOLOCK)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Asset WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON Asset.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
     LEFT OUTER JOIN AssetHierarchy WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON AssetHierarchy.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
     WHERE WO.WOPK = 10109)
     )
     AND (d.Active = 1)
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
       WO.WOPK,
       md.PK,
       d.LocationType,
       d.DocumentID,
       d.DocumentName,
       md.ModuleID,
       d.DocumentTypeDesc,
       d.Location,
       md.PrintWithWO,
       md.SendWithEmail,
       md.DisplayLink,
       md.RowVersionDate,
       d.Photo,
       MCModule.TitleforDocumentList,
       d.DocumentText
     FROM WOdocument md WITH (NOLOCK)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Document d WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON md.DocumentPK = d.DocumentPK
     INNER JOIN MCModule WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON md.ModuleID = MCModule.ModuleID
     INNER JOIN WO WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON WO.WOPK = md.WOPK
     WHERE (WO.WOPK IN (SELECT
       WOPK
     FROM WO WITH (NOLOCK)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Asset WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON Asset.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
     LEFT OUTER JOIN AssetHierarchy WITH (NOLOCK)
       ON AssetHierarchy.AssetPK = WO.AssetPK
     WHERE WO.WOPK = 10109)
    )
     AND (d.Active = 1)
      ORDER BY WO.WOPK, md.ModuleID, d.DocumentID
    )
) sub
```

Comment: I don't believe this is correct -- it will return the first record from the first query.  It will then add that result to the other records from the `union`...  Should be `select top 1 * from (your entire query here) t`

Comment: sgeddes, yes I didn't see how long the query was when I first answered,  when I went through and formatted the query I saw the unions, thanks for the comment, updated